# How to correctly deal with System.Nullable<T> fields of LinqToSql classes?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I've got a table with some nullable double fields. Working with LinqToSQL trying to use the field directly I get

> Argument type System.Nullable is not assignable to parameter type double

How do I deal with this correctly?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with LINQ. Consider a more general SO search for dealing with Nullable values.

Comment: You should really post actual code along with the actual error message. Please don't make us guess what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Linq. It's got to do with conversion between `double` and `double?`/`Nullable<double>`.

Implicit conversion from `double?` to `double` is not allowed:

```
double? foo ;
double  bar = foo ;
```

- You can reference the double value directly:

  ```
    double? foo ;
    double  bar = foo.Value ;
  ```

  This will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the `Nullable<T>` is null (that is, `.HasValue` is false).
- You can cast it:

  ```
    double? foo ;
    double  bar = (double) foo ;
  ```

  Again, you'll get an exception if the `Nullabl<T>` is null.
- You can use the null coalescing operator to assign a default value if the `Nullable<T>` is null:

  ```
    double? foo ;
    double  bar = foo ?? -1.0 ;
  ```

  This, natch, avoids the NullReferenceException` problem.
- You can use the ternary operator in the same vein as the null coalescing operator:

  ```
    double? foo ;
    double  bar = ( foo.HasValue ? foo.Value : -2 ) ;
  ```
- Finally, you can use regular conditional logic to follow an alternative path:

  ```
    double? foo ;
    double  bar ;

    if ( foo.HasValue )
    {
      doSomething(foo.Value) ;
    }
    else
    {
      doSomething() ;
    }
  ```

Those are about the options. Which is correct? I don't know. It depends on your context.

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
double value = theObject.TheProperty.GetValueOrDefault();
```

When you have a `Nullable<T>` and you need a value of type `T`. This will normalize any `null` to the default value of `T`, which will be 0.0 for a double. If you want something *other* than the default, you can work around it another way.

```
double value = theObject.TheProperty ?? 1d; // where 1 replaces any null
```

Comment: +1 for the null coalescing operator `??` and `GetValueOrDefault`

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches.

1. Use nullable types such as double?.  Your entity class can have a property of double? and your client code will work with the nullable type.

   ```
   public class Person
   {

       public string FirstName { get; set; }

       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public double? Age { get; set; }

       public Person() 
       {
       }
       public Person( IDataRecord record )
       {
           FirstName = (string) record["first_name"];
           LastName = (string) record["last_name"];
           Age = (double?) record["age"];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Write a wrapper around the assignment that chooses a safe default value if NULL is present.  I like to use an extension method off the data record class and put a SafeConvert method there.

Answer (score -1):

You can either cast it: `double yourVariable = (double)ValueFromDb` or you can just grab the Value of the `double?`: `double yourVaraible = ValueFromDb.Value`.  Either is correct.

Comment: And both may *explode*. Consider `double v = nullabledouble ?? somedefaultdouble`, such as `double age = nullableAge ?? Double.NaN` (yes, I count in fractional years these days ;-)

Comment: Make sure that you use the 2nd version by checking if the nullable value `has` value or not