# Nullable object must have a value - why?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ query

```
from p in dc.Purchases
where invoiceNumber == null || p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value
select p;
```

The 'invoiceNumber' is a nullable int - when it's null, the program throws a 'Nullable object must have a value error'. Why is this when it's explicitly checking if it's null first? Is there a way around this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any difference when you change the null check to `invoiceNumber.HasValue`?

Comment: What Linq provider are you using? Linq to sql, entity framework, linq to objects ... ?

Comment: LINQ to SQL. No difference when using HasValue

Comment: just a guess but maybe it's the order that the || evaluates, what happens if you try p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value || invoiceNumber == null ?

Comment: I'd guess it's the way linq works, in that it doesn't discard the second half of the "or" statement if the first side is true. You'd have to check again before accessing the value

Comment: does it happen in case of replacing 'p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value' with 'p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber'?

Comment: check this question on nullable types in linq: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233117/how-to-correctly-deal-with-system-nullablet-fields-of-linqtosql-classes

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with your query. From the code you've supplied I assume that `invoiceNumber` is a local variable or a parameter. If this is the case, then why are you even checking if `invoiceNumber == null` in your query? Such check should be done separately from the query:

```
if(invoiceNumber == null)
{
    return dc.Purchases; 
    // the query would evaluate to this because invoiceNumber == null will allways return true.
}
else
{
    return 
        from p in dc.Purchases 
        where p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value
        select p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from p in dc.Purchases
where invoiceNumber == null ||(invoiceNumber!=null && p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value)
select p;
```

Comment: doesn't make sense - the || operator will evaluate it's second argument only if the first one evaluates to false

Comment: Not in LINQ-to-SQL. The query is translated to SQL and all terms of the expression are evaluated. There is no short-circuit, as in C#. Use the null-coalescing operator ?? (works like ISNULL) or use the normal SQL null behavior that evaluates to false when the value is null: `where p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber`. Alternatively, add a separate .Where() condition when invoiceNumber is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
from p in dc.Purchases
where (invoiceNumber == null ? p.InvNumber == null : p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value)
select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
from p in dc.Purchases 
where (invoiceNumber ?? p.InvNumber) == p.InvNumber
select p;
```

but, I would pose the question, if `invoiceNumber` is `null` why run this statement?

Comment: If it's null, it should retrieve everything

Comment: @Chris, so, another statement without that where clause would be more efficient for your database to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HasValue property to check if a Nullable has value.

```
from p in dc.Purchases
where !invoiceNumber.HasValue || p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value
select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell, but I suspect that `p.InvNumber` is nullable as well. In that case, don't use the `.Value`:

```
from p in dc.Purchases
where invoiceNumber == null || p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber
select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to check for null explicitly. 
there might two cases with the nullable values either it will be null or has some value.

e.g.

CASE 1-

```
 int ? invoiceNumber = null;
 var prods = from p in dc.Purchases 
             where p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber
             select p;
```

CASE 2-

```
 int ? invoiceNumber = 100;
 var prods = from p in dc.Purchases 
             where p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber
             select p;
```

same linq statement will work in both the cases.

Comment: Why does case 1 have a where clause?

Comment: I just want to depict that same linq query will work in both the cases. either invoiceNumber is null or it has some value.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept of `nullable` type is... the underlying type will have all the values specified in its range + a `null` value, to increase the flexibility with the database programming.

nullable types has two readonly properties
1) `HasValue` 2) `Value`

`HasValue` is `boolean` type and it is set to true automatically if Value has some value in it.
So, for comparisions, you have to use `HasValue` first and then `Value`. If u use `Value` directly, and if it is `null`, then the above exception will be thrown.

keeping these in mind, I doubt this fragment too,. where `invoiceNumber == null` 
you should try `invoiceNumber.Value==null` (not invoiceNumber)

or

```
where invoiceNumber.HasValue && p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber.Value
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in Linq-to-Sql - it's trying to convert where statement to SQL so invoiceNumber.Value can be called even it's null.

Please just try where `invoiceNumber == null || p.InvNumber == invoiceNumber`.

Hope it'll help.